# Initialization order of constant initialized variable with static storage duration

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, static-initialization

Based on the following code snippet:

```
const int a = 42;
const int b = a;
```

We know that constant intialization is performed for both these variables, and that constant initialization is static initialization.

Since the order of static initialization is unspecified (unlike dynamic initialization, which has its order specified), would this not possibly result in undefined behavior, as if the static initialization of `b` occured before `a`, it would be reading uninitialized memory?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201236/discussion-on-question-by-krystian-s-initialization-order-of-constant-initialize).

Comment: There is no undefined behavior from "reading uninitialized memory". If you mean indeterminate value, only objects with automatic and dynamic storage duration have it b4 initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let us clarify the context: We are considering initialisation of variables with **static** storage duration. This initialisation actually has two parts: Static phase and dynamic phase. The static phase happens first, and there are no dependencies between variables in this phase. The order of initialisation only matters for **dynamic** initialisation of variables with static storage.

Order of (dynamic) initialisation of static variables is not unspecified in general. It is generally unspecified *between separate translation units*, and also in some cases within a single TU.

```
const int a = dynamic_init();
const int b = a;
```

If these variables are in a single TU as it would seem from the example, then the order is specified: `a` is declared first, and therefore it is initialised first.

```
const int a = 42;
const int b = a;
```

42 is a constant expression. Therefore `a` has constant initialisation, which is static initialisation (not dynamic). Therefore order of initialisation does not matter for this variable.

`a` is also a constant expression, because `a` is `const` variable with static storage and a constant initialiser. Therefore `b`  also has non-dynamic initialisation.  Therefore order of initialisation does not matter for this variable.

---

With the context out of the way:

> Since the order of static initialization is unspecified [...], would this not possibly result in undefined behavior, as if the static initialization of b occured before a

Just because standard doesn't specify the order, doesn't mean that the implementation can do whatever it wants. Standard says that the static initialisation happens, and the implementation is responsible for performing it. It must choose an order that works as specified.

In practice, the order doesn't matter, because it is not observable to the program.  Both variables are initialised to 42 no matter how the implementation chooses to achieve that.

Comment: I understand the difference between static and dynamic intialization, and I mean everything I said exactly how I said it.

Comment: @KrystianS good. The latter part of my answer will be relevant to you.

Comment: Anyways, as you said, both have constant initialization, which is static initialization. Static initialization has no defined order. Therefore, it's fully possible for `b` to be initialized before `a`, which would result in `b` reading the value of `a` before `a` was initialized.

Comment: @KrystianS why would constant initialisation involve reading a variable?

Comment: Because that is exactly how the standard defines it.

Comment: Again, the way the standard defines how constant expressions work is not literal replacement with the value; the normal rules of the abstract machine still apply. `a` still denotes an object of static storage duration.

Comment: @KrystianS As per the as-if rule, the program does not need to follow the rules of the abstract machine at all. Only the observable effects must be the same. The program has no way of observing the order of static initialiation, so that order does not matter to the concrete machine. If the implementation wishes to follow such behaviour of abstract machine and access memory of `a`, then the implementation must take steps to ensure the correct order. But it doesn't have to, because it already knows the value at compile time.

Comment: You're going into implementation land, which isn't what this is about. Given the current way that constant expressions are defined, it's just a type of expression that can appear in special places, and it's rules are no different from any other expression. Sure, the intent is compile time evaluation, but from the point of view of the standard, it's just a special, more constrained expression. Nothing says it must be evaluated at compile time, the standard has no notion of that.

Comment: @KrystianS Standard just says that the initialisation happens. It doesn't say that it happens, but may have undefined behaviour. Thus there is no undefined behaviour. If reading uninitialised memory would have undefined behaviour, then that is something that doesn't happen during static initialisation.

Comment: Undefined behavior need not be explicit, and in this case, it could come as a consequence of something else (eg: reading the value of an object outside of it's lifetime)

Answer (score 0):

It is specified by [intro.execution]

The full-expressions for such two declarations are their init-declarators, respectively. As per [intro.execution#5]

> A full-expression is.
>
> > - an init-declarator ([dcl.decl]) or a mem-initializer ([class.base.init]), including the constituent expressions of the initializer.

The associated initialization is considered as a part of its full-expression

> For an initializer, performing the initialization of the entity (including evaluating default member initializers of an aggregate) is also considered part of the full-expression.

So, their order of evaluation are defined by the following:

> Every value computation and side effect associated with a full-expression is **sequenced before** every value computation and side effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.